# Dynamic Network Name Lookup

Tags: domain-name-system

I want to make a "dynamic hosts-file server", in lack of a better name, i want to make a machine that asks my other machines what their name is and then lists it in the DNS or some hosts directory.

I'm on square one here so first of all i just need a push in the right direction, maybe getting to know a few of the terms used for a usable google query.

This is how far i am:

- Ive looked at something called wins server and realized that i need a windows server for that, im using 100% linux where 80% is ubuntu.
- Ive looked in to static ip adresses but because of my hosting situation i need them to stay dynamic. And i use alot of virtual machines, so i need it to be dynamic.
- The server is connected to a DHCP host. All critical systems are on static IP adresses (critical = esxi servers and SAN)

Any help, notes, terms, small blows in the sails would be nice!

Comment: Forgive me if I don't quite understand what you're asking but it seems to me that you're looking for a DNS server that supports dynamic DNS. Implemented in conjunction with your DHCP server and assigning the appropriate DNS Domain Name (DHCP option 15) will accomplish your goal. You can also statically assign the DNS Domain Name and/or DNS search suffixes to your clients.

Comment: i want to be on server1 and write http://server2/ and see the webpage on server2 - Right now if i have to find the webpage on server 2 i have to go to the router, find the servername on the dhcp list, if im lucky, else i have to search through 20 "Unknown", get the ip address and enter it to get it, so i was thinking, there must be an easier way.

Comment: There is an easier way. It's called DNS. Look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As joeqwerty mentioned, you seem to be asking for dynamic DNS (DDNS). Depending on what you control in this setup, it could be relatively simple to configure.

**If you control the DHCP server**, you can have it use the information from a DHCP lease to update DNS records. This works if you have DDNS as a service (e.g., Dyn) or with a local DNS server (using, say, `bind9`). In the former case, most routers I've seen have some built-in interface for updating DDNS services; if your DHCP server is not a router, you can always try `ddclient`. In the latter case, it's a (fairly) simple integration between `dhcpd` and `bind`.

**If you don't control the DHCP server**, you would have to configure the clients to update the DNS server themselves. Again, `ddclient` works with major DDNS providers. For a local DNS server, there are tutorials out there detailing various Bash and/or Perl scripts to run on the client to achieve the same effect.

Of course, all this assumes that you either 
A) have (or can acquire) a registered domain with DNS service through a major DNS provider, or 
B) can spare a static IP for a locally-hosted DNS server.

Comment: Ok, i know about dynamic dns. But since this is on a local network (lan), will this work here? Because my knowledge about dynamic dns, extends to a webservice that points to the gateway, not mapping virtual servers on my local network.

Comment: You can always run a local DNS server for your LAN domain. I mentioned bind9 because it is a popular nameserver package for Ubuntu. It's not as straightforward to get DDNS working for a local server, but the information in my answer should be enough to get you to a more comprehensive tutorial.

Comment: I did indeed get a lot of puzzle pieces, right now i'm trying to identify the corner pieces so i can start putting it together.

Answer (score 0):

Without some service on your servers, you will not be able to ask them their name.

There are existing auto-discovery protocols bedsides WINS.  Avahi/Bonjour works cross platform an allows servers to announce their presence and the services they provide.

If your servers have fixed addresses, the standard practice is to list them in the internal DNS file.  This requires an extra step when you provision and decommission servers.

You can use `nmap` to discover servers and services. Checking these against your DNS data will allow you to identify untracked and missing servers.

Tools like `arpwatch` allow you to track which IP addresses are in use, and can be used to discover IP address conflicts.

`DHCP` can serve static IP addresses, but would require you to configure your servers to use DHCP instead of configured fixed addresses.  Configuring fixed addresses for servers is considered best practice.  Using DHCP opens up the risk of man-in-the-middle attacks on your infrastructure.